# Django is_staff permission decorator

Tags: django, permissions, admin, decorator

I am trying to limit access to pages using 2 user levels. Superuser and admin.
Super user is a regular Django user with 'is_superuser' assigned.
Admin user is also a regular user with only the 'is_staff' permission assigned.

The problem is that when i use this decorator for an admin user, it doesn't pass the test:

```
@permission_required('is_staff')
def my_view(....)
```

`@permission_required('is_staff')` returns false for anonymous users. (correct)
`@permission_required('is_superuser')` only returns true for superusers (correct)
`@permission_required('is_staff')` returns FALSE for users with the 'is_staff' perm assigned. (wrong).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I should note i am using Django 1.3 with python 2.6.1

Answer (score 125, accepted):

`is_staff` isn't a permission so instead of `permission_required` you could use:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff)
```

or

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required

@staff_member_required
```

Comment: That did it, though the fact that is_superuser exists and is_staff doesn't is quite misleading.

Comment: i added another option which is more intuitive (staff_member_required).

Comment: `@permission_required('is_superuser')` returns `True` for superusers because `@permission_required` always returns `True` for superusers regardless of whether that permission exists or not (which it does not in this case).  This is assuming you are using the default authentication backend.

Comment: The build-in decorator "staff_member_required" is convinient, but I would use it with care, as it seems not to be officially documented.

Comment: @bjunix I'd say `staff_member_required` is safe to use now by your standards. I found it via a "See Also" block in the "[Using the Django authentication system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/)" page of the manual.

Comment: @ssokolow Yes, you are right, the `staff_member_required` decorator is documented by now: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#the-staff-member-required-decorator

Comment: how can I say `raise_exception=True` with any of these?

Comment: django-braces provides mixins for CBVs for superuser/staff "requirement": https://django-braces.readthedocs.io/en/latest/access.html#staffuserrequiredmixin

Answer (score 10):

for Class Based Views you can add `permission_required('is_staff')` to the `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

url(r'^your-url$', permission_required('is_staff')(YourView.as_view()), name='my-view'),
```

Comment: I didn't try, but I wonder if 'is_staff' works as expected here.

Answer (score 9):

For class-based views, the [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) is convenient, e.g.

```
class ImportFilePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):
  def test_func(self):
    return self.request.user.is_staff
  ...
```

Comment: Lol just came across my own answer only a few days later ... early signs of alzheimer :D

Comment: Lol just came across it again :/

Answer (score 0):

A variant of @arie 's answer without lambda which might be a tad faster (but I didn't check):

```
import operator
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

@user_passes_test(operator.attrgetter('is_staff'))
def my_view(....)
```

Having said that, I think the better approach is to create a `Permission` for your view and use it with the `permission_required` decorator.